# ElasticSearch Ignoring words having one single letter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a beginner in ElasticSearch, I have an application that uses elasticSearch to look for ingredients in a given food or fruit...
I'm facing a problem with scoring if the user for example tapes: `"Vitamine d"`
ElasticSearch will give the `"vitamine"` phrase that has the best scoring even if the phrase `"Vitamine D"` exists and normally it should have the highest score.
I see that if the second word `"d"` in my case is just one letter then elastic search will ignore it.

I did another example: `"vitamine b12"` and I had the correct score.

Here is the query that the application send to the server:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "constNomFr": {
              "query": "vitamine d"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "constNomFr": {
              "value": "vitamine d",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [
      "alimentDtos"
    ]
  }
}
```

What could I modify to make it work?

Thank you so much.

Comment: There are certain mapping options that could cause single-letter terms to not be indexed. But you'd need to post your mapping to be sure.

Comment: If your "constNomFr" field were using the standard analyzer then your query should work as described. I tested this by creating documents for vitamins A-Z, A8-Z8, and A12-Z12 in a temporary index. Searching this index using your query gave me only a single result (the "vitamin D" result).

Comment: If the `Vitamin D` is a field that only contains one ingredient what I would do is to index that field as a Keyword, that way it will be an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify your ingredients, I recommend you to index them on a separate field "ingredients" setting it's type to `keyword`. This way you can use a term filter and you can even run aggregations.

You may already have your documents indexed that way, in that case if your are using the default mapping, just run your query against `your_field_name.keyword`.

If you don't have your ingredients indexed as an array then you should take a look to the elasticsearch [analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) to choose or build the right one.